# Rewrite rule-- If incoming request is not consist of certain characters then rewrite to other URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to construct a rule that checks if the incoming request is of certain terms, if no, then reroute to other URL?

For example, I have a website `my.example.com`. If the incoming URL is `my.example.com/login` then it should execute that request. If it's something else (not `login`), then the request must be reroute to `your.example.com`. For example,

- `my.example.com/login2` must reroute to `your.example.com/login2`
- `my.example.com/nologin` must reroute to `your.example.com/nologin`
- `my.example.com/getname` must reroute to `your.example.com/getname`

And of course, if it's

- `my.example.com/login` must reroute to `my.example.com/login`

How to use [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^login$ http://your.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I used example.com by purpose and so should you. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.myexample\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.myexample.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I don't think your script does what is intended... for example, I don't see any logic involving login and yourexample.com?

Comment: Ah ok, sorry i misunderstand the question first time round.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you've asked for, but would do it by using .htaccess to direct all requests (valid or not) through to one file & then using server-side scripting (e.g. PHP in my case) to switch through the valid options, catching anything else with a default that redirects to the other URL.

e.g. this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

sends anything that isn't a request for an actual file or directory to index.php